# SQL Server Database Project Schema Compare case insensitive

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

Is there option at Schema Compare feature SQL Server Database Project?

I have same table name at different server. But it was detected as Different. I do not want it decided as different (case Insensitive)

[image: one]

Please show me the option if any.

[image: two]

Comment: I'm also looking for a resolution to this... did you ever find out?

Comment: @Stark Not Yet. I have updated my Database Project (for VS 2015) but not solved yet. I do not know is this feature exist or not in VS 2017. Or maybe there is newer version of DB Project? Not checked it yet. Maybe We can vote to this functionality. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/category/53186-sql-server-and-data-tools